# How to remove excess vertical spaces occur in the equation?

Tags: equations, braces

I would like to remove the vertical white spaces that occur when compiling this equation. Kindly help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{8}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Vast[\big(\gamma\big) - {\bigg(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)}^{\vast(\dfrac{\bigg(\Gamma- 
\dfrac{\psi}{\Psi}\bigg)}{\delta+\Delta}\vast)}\Vast] 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose  1. to use the various `matrix` environments,; 2. to use the `medsize` environment from `nccmath` for the exponent (it is ~80 % of `\displaystyle`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}\bigl(\gamma\bigr) - {\Bigl(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\Bigr)}^{\begin{medsize}\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\Bigl(\Gamma-
\frac{\psi}{\Psi}\Bigr)}{\delta+\Delta}\end{pmatrix}\end{medsize}}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked very well. Thank you very much.